# Loop through variables and their values bash

Tags: bash

I have a of variable names. I want to loop through the list and check that the variable has a value.

I have seen answers for variable expansion but I am getting bad substitution when trying to incorporate them into my loop. This is roughly w

```
vars=("username" "password")

for var in ${vars[@]}
do
   if [ -z "${<get variable value>}" ]
   then
      echo " $var value is empty"
      exit 1
   fi
done
```

Comment: What error exactly..?

Comment: @Inian the error is `bad substitution`, when I try something like `echo ${!var@}`

Comment: You probably wanted `[ -z "${!var}" ]`.

Answer (score 3):

c.f. the [Bash Parameter Expension](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) rules.

```
$ cat tst
vars=("username" "password")

for var in ${vars[@]}
do if [ -z "${!var}" ]
   then echo " $var value is empty"
   else echo " $var value is '${!var}'"
   fi
done

$ ./tst
 username value is empty
 password value is empty

$ export username=me

$ ./tst
 username value is 'me'
 password value is empty
```

If you use `${!var@}` it's also returning your array, `vars`, which produces a syntax error because there are too many tokens to `[` (test).

If you use `[[` instead it will show you both, though that still isn't what you want.

Either remove the `@` or rename the array.

Comment: I tried copying your example, and am still getting `bad substitution` error for line 4, which is `do if [ -z "${!var}" ]`

Comment: Are you sure you're using `bash`?

Comment: No! my shell was set to zsh. If I switch to bash, then the syntax above works. I thought `#!/bin/bash` at the start of script would cause bash to be used?

Comment: @kravb : The #! line takes effect only if you invoke the script directly by its name. Since you did not show how you called the script, I can't say what you did wrong. Aside from this: You can use zsh, if you prefer. You just have then to use zsh-syntax: `"${(P)var}"`

Comment: @user1934428 thank you. I was using `source script.txt` to execute. Should I change to `sh script.sh`? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: @kravb: I don't know; it depends what you want to achieve. If you `source` the script, it is processed by the shell which issues the source command (bash, ksh, zsh,...), and the syntax must adhere to this shell. If you run it as `sh scriptsh` you create a child process, which is POSIX shell, and the syntax you are using must adhere to POSIX shell. First make up your mind, what programming language you want to write your code in, and then we can think about how to run your code.

Comment: Don't us `sh` to run it if you want `bash`.

Answer (score 2):

you can also do like this

```
vars=("username" "password")

for var in "${vars[@]}"; do
   if [ -z "${!var}" ]; then
      echo "$var value is empty"
      exit 1
   fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If using `bash 4.2+` you could use a nameref:

```
vars=("username" "password")
  
for var in "${vars[@]}"
do
    declare -n myvar="${var}"                       # nameref

    if [ -z "${myvar}" ]
    then
        echo " $var value is empty"
    else
        echo " $var value is ${myvar}"
    fi
done
```

With the variables unset/undefined:

```
unset username password
```

The `for` loop generates:

```
 username value is empty
 password value is empty
```

If we make some assignments:

```
username=bubbles
password=999gumball
```

The `for` loop generates:

```
 username value is bubbles
 password value is 999gumball
```